# Can't create topic through an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, terminal

Im able to delete and Update topics on my website through an API but for some reason I cant figure out why I am unable to Create a topic.

im running on my terminal

```
 curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token jX4h98/B3Jx9R0JXYtqeRjzNBzLJs/AFbXckBnkcGKKcuSMUFJ5dqpPbDgFki4G0D5TVrbfvR685Jjo6CQ2qUg==" -X POST -d '{"topic": {"name":"Drastic Voyage: Part II", "description":"The team\'s mission inside Dr. Kovacs goes awry, and they are blacklisted by the CIA."}}' http://localhost:3000/api/v1/topics/
```

and all i get is a `>` on my terminal .

here is my Create method in my API Topics controller :

```
  def create
    topic = Topic.new(topic_params)

    if topic.valid?
      topic.save!
      render json: topic.to_json, status: 201
    else
      render json: {error: "Topic is invalid", status: 400}, status: 400
    end
  end
```

my routes :

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update]
      resources :topics, except: [:edit, :new]

    end
  end
```

any idea what might i be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use single quote within single quote in shell. If you absolutely need to do it in one line, you'd have to break the string in half and use concatenation, like: `The team'\''s mission inside`. Full command as follows.

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token jX4h98/B3Jx9R0JXYtqeRjzNBzLJs/AFbXckBnkcGKKcuSMUFJ5dqpPbDgFki4G0D5TVrbfvR685Jjo6CQ2qUg==" -X POST -d '{"topic": {"name":"Drastic Voyage: Part II", "description":"The team'\''s mission inside Dr. Kovacs goes awry, and they are blacklisted by the CIA."}}' http://localhost:3000/api/v1/topics/
```

Or use Postman. It's pretty handy. https://www.getpostman.com/